# Python: More elegant way to add optional parameters to method call

Tags: python, python-3.x, optional-parameters, keyword-argument

This will seem trivial perhaps, but it is a condition that I run into fairly frequently and would like to find a more elegant way of writing this code. The method, while not terribly relevant to the question, takes a text value and an optional is_checked value to create a radio button (using dominate). In this case, I can't set 'checked' to None, or false - it either has to be there or not. It doesn't seem like I should have to write the 'input' line twice though, just to optionally add an argument.

```
def _get_radio_button(text: str, is_checked=False):

    with label(text, cls="radio-inline") as lbl:
        if is_checked:
            input(text, type="radio", name="optradio", checked='checked')
        else:
            input(text, type="radio", name="optradio")

    return lbl
```

This would be my second approach, but it is the same lines of code and less readable - though perhaps a tiny bit more DRY.

```
a = dict(type='radio', name='optradio')
if is_checked: 
    a['checked']='checked'
with label(text, cls="radio-inline") as lbl:
    input(text, **a)
```

Question: How can I handle this code case with the fewest lines possible without sacrificing readability?

Comment: Your second option is perfectly reasonable, just use a sensible name for the  kwargs dictionary, like for example `kwargs` instead of `a`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code looks fine, except obviously for the naming of `a`, which could be `input_opts` or something like that.

Another possibility to make it a bit clearer is to use direct keyword arguments for the common stuff and just inject the optional ones using `**`. When only one is optional, this can be quite short, e.g.:

```
checked_arg = {'checked': 'checked'} if is_checked else {}
with label(text, cls="radio-inline") as lbl:
    input(text, type="radio", name="optradio", **checked_arg)
```

Comment: I see what you did there - I like it. I suspect this will get the answer but want to give it a bit so see if anything else pops out. Thank you for taking the time to respond.

Comment: @SteveJ another possible option is to change it to be "def f(text, **attrs)", call the inner function as "input(..., **attrs)" and call the main as "f('some text', checked='checked')" which is arguably more explicit and potentially more flexible if wanting to supply additional attributes but all depends how you want it to look/be used...

Comment: @JonClements That would work as well, but the trouble with that approach is that it exposes construction of `input` parameters to callers of `_get_radio_button` - including the wart of not being able to provide a `None` value for `checked`. I would avoid that, unless it was clear from the rest of the code that `_get_radio_button` is only a thin wrapper for calling `input`.

Comment: @user4815162342 indeed - why I'm hesitant to suggest it as a proper answer and like you say it's tricky to tell without more context. It does at a first glance look like `input` is fairly generic and could be `partial`'d for different types and just throw `**kwargs` at it... but *shrugs* - we don't know.

Comment: Thank you user4815162342 for the answer and @JonClements, for the additional discussion. I intentionally didn't give much context because I wanted to have a solution for the generic case. This solution is just what I asked for, DRY, simple, and readable. On its own, it doesn't seem like much of a difference, but those lines add up. More importantly, it gives me more tools to work with in my use of method arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Only as concept :)  You can decorate in this way own or alien (library) functions. Even more, you can make decorator as class (with `__call__` method which will decorate underlying function) which can be parameterized with simple "morphisms" of underlying function arguments (they may be list of functions - as arguments of decorator class constructor). Also you can make more declarative style decorator and to inspect underlying function arguments (for default values, for example) - you are limited only by own fantasy :) So:

```
from functools import wraps

def adapt_gui_args(callable):
    @wraps(callable)
    def w(*args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.pop('is_checked', False): kwargs['checked'] = 'checked'
        return callable(*args, **kwargs)
    return w

# may be decorated with adapt_gui_args if it's your function
def input(*args, **kwargs):
    print("args: ", args)
    print("kwargs: ", kwargs)

# decorate input function outside its source body
input = adapt_gui_args(input)

def test(is_checked=False):
    input(1, 2, type="radio", is_checked=is_checked)

test(False)
test(True)
```

Comment: (chuckling) -- I can barely understand it and I can't think of a time it wouldn't be overkill, but I love it - thank you for teaching me something new.

Comment: The trouble with this solution is that, while `adapt_gui_args` sounds generic, it's in fact closely tied to the semantics of `input` (and even then to its single `checked` parameter, which is converted from `is_checked`). There is no reason for such code not to reside in `test`, as it does in the OP's code. On the other hand, a truly generic version of the decorator that accepted arbitrary arguments describing the transformation like `is_checked` -> `checked` would be actually useful.